# Eclipse crashes; Log file states file is missing when its not

Tags: java, eclipse, rad

Every time I try to start up one of my workspaces, it shows a progress information popup. from here it is unresponsive. After checking the .log file, there is the following;

```
ENTRY com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxrs.common 4 0 2014-12-09 04:34:57.701
!MESSAGE FinancialDistributionPCStub [in FinancialDistributionPCStub.java 
[in com.lmig.cmit.rt.bo.business.test [in connectorModule [in T7BOService]]]] does not exist
!STACK 1
Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [FinancialDistributionPCStub [in FinancialDistributionPCStub.java [in com.lmig.cmit.rt.bo.business.test 
[in connectorModule [in T7BOService]]]] does not exist]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.newNotPresentException(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceType.getAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxrs.finder.AbstractFinder.findWSAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ast.ws.jaxrs.finder.AbstractSourceFinder.resourceChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ccl.ws.internal.finder.core.notifier.impl.NotifyResourceChangedJob.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Unknown Source)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 969 2014-12-09 04:34:57.702
!MESSAGE FinancialDistributionPCStub [in FinancialDistributionPCStub.java [in com.lmig.cmit.rt.bo.business.test [in connectorModule [in T7BOService]]]] does not exist

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.jsp.core 4 4 2014-12-09 04:35:15.521
!MESSAGE A workspace crash was detected. The previous session did not exit normally. Not using saved taglib indexes.
```

The file FinancialDistributionPCStub is present when i check the directory, so I don't know what the problem is

Thus far I've tried moving org.eclipse.core.resources and closing the editors then moving it back again and it hasn't made any difference

EDIT: Based off a comment regarding permissions, I have changed the permissions of the file to read/write for all groups and it will now load the workspace. The error has also disappeared from the log file.

EDIT: And now its occurring again

Comment: This file is present, but is it available in reading ? (check permission)

Comment: it has the same permission as every other file in the directory, and it is halfway down the list alphabetically. There doesn't seem to be any problems with the rest of the files

Comment: I changed the permissions and it now seems to have worked, and the error is no longer present. Strange given that its never happened before this week, and the file in question had the exact same permission as every other file within the directory